# Is it feasible to create a game in godot using little to no GDScript

Tags: c#, c++, godot

I am trying to get more into game development, I have very little experience with it. I've been messing around a bit with the Godot engine and am slowly starting to understand it more. I have some experience with C# and C++, both of which can be used with Godot (to my knowledge, correct me if I'm wrong), and it also has its own language, GDScript. From what I've seen the language looks a lot different from any I've used (C#, C++, and Java), and I really don't want to learn it, I especially don't want to learn a new engine and a new language at the same time.

So basically would it be possible to create a game in Godot using very little to no GDScript without missing out on features or making life a whole lot harder? Another way to word it could be 'is there any thing that is impossible or very much harder to do in C# or C++ than if you were using GDScript?'

Sorry if this is too broad or anything, I'll try to fix it if need be

Comment: Voting to close as "what technology to choose" in disguise. (Or "does technology X supports feature Y".)

Comment: I can see where you're coming from...but I actually have already committed to Godot anyways, so I'm not trying to ask whether to use it or not. And I'm not exactly asking if it has a particular feature, but to what extent you have to use a certain one, which I'm not convinced is a 'does technology x support feature y' question. Still though, I did get a satisfactory answer so I guess I don't care too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Godot can be used fully without any type of GDScript interaction.

C# has official engine support, and can be used instead of GDScript in all places because the way C# scripts are loaded is similar. In fact, all of the "built-in" functions available in GDScript are made available in C#, typically as static methods under `Godot.GD`.
I personally have had a very smooth experience with Godot Mono, and recently competed in a Game Jam using only C#, no GDScript at all, without any issues.
On a personal project of mine, the only time knowledge of GDScript became an issue was when I imported [a plugin for an in-game dropdown console](https://github.com/DmitriySalnikov/godot-console) which I wanted to bind to my C# scripts (and fix as well because it was very broken at the time of writing this).
However in my case I come from a Python background, so GDScript was very familiar to me. In your case, it may not be worth using GDScript plugins, but it's completely up to you.

C++ is a completely different monster that I cannot speak much about, but any C++ must be compiled with the engine as a module and does not support scripting in the same way that C# and GDScript do, but it's the option many people still take so go for it.

Overall, the answer is yes, you can build complete games without touching GDScript.
**Most** examples in the official documentation offer both GDScript and C# snippets.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I am not an expert in the Godot engine and have only used it on occasion*

The Godot engine should be just fine for building a solo project from scratch with little to no coding. Godot does support C# and C++ for some instances where you want to implement a niche feature/idea for your game, and it should be fine to just learn their visual editor beyond that.

Godot is a nice middle tier engine: a bit more handholdy and easy to start with than Unity3D/Unreal, but more advanced than RPGEngine. Nothing is wrong with starting out with any of these, in fact I would say that the best thing to do as a burgeoning gamedev is to *just pick one* and go with it.

**TL;DR**: It looks great to start out with, get going!